# How to throw the exception from Storage Extension to Tridion GUI Publishing Queue?

Tags: 2013-sp1, storage-extensions, publishingfailed

We are using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and have implemented a Storage Extension.
When an exception occurs within the Storage Extension, we would like to display the error message to the user who published that item. Though the root cause of the failure is logged in the log files, that message is not there in the `state xml`. The user gets to see messages like:

> Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed. Unable to prepare transaction:
>   tcm:0-xxxxxx-66560

The user would rather like to see the actual reason why the deployment failed. How can this be done within the Storage Extension?